# Invalidate all existing Cookies & Access Tokens, for Maintenance Mode

Tags: authentication, oauth, jwt, session-cookies

Is there a way to make to my fairly standard authentication code reject every previously granted authentication token / cookie, and require all users to re-login. Triggered by either a DB/config change, or a code release?

---

I'm looking after a system with a number of components. There are a couple of different archeological layers, built on top of a single shared DB - different parts of the system built in different ways with different tech over the course of time.

The login management all *eventually* calls down into a single backend login service authenticating against a simple (user, password hash, roles) system, but there are a couple of different "how do we manage sessions and persisted login status" systems in play layered over the top of that. Though I believe that all of them boil down to either a cookie or a JWT, and I **think** that all of them are using some variation on OAuth.

*I'm going to use "voucher" to refer to both "Cookies" and "JWTs", since "token" is already used for the JWTs specifically.*

As I understand it, once a user is logged in, when a user hits a general server endpoint (whether it's a page on an MVC controller, or an API end point) the system checks the request for either the cookie or JWT, and says "ah, they've got a voucher here that hasn't expired and says that authenticated." i.e. it doesn't actively call the login logic on every call.

And from glancing at the code it looks like there's also a special "refresh authentication" system that means that even when the auth voucher expires, it doesn't necessarily call the login logic again - it may just do something along the lines of "oh, I remember you you've got a recent auth voucher and a valid refresh voucher have a new auth voucher".

Is that understanding about right for how OAuth authentication systems generally work?

---

My scenario:

The system has no Maintenance Mode.

We can obviously turn it off and manually do deployments and DB updates. But if we want the administrators to be able to log in and make business changes, or for the testers to be able to log in and do stuff, then *everyone* can do that.

And now we have a release we need to do, where that's a problem - we need the system up and running, but for it to be impossible for an average user (i.e. a user without a dedicated "Maintenance Access" role) to interact with the system in any way.

Enforcing that during the login sequence is trivial - just a DB/config flag declaring the system to be in Maintenance Mode, and a role to check whether the User who's trying to log in is allowed to do so despite that. But obviously we need to lock out all the users who were *already* authenticated and using the system when we activate MM, and I'm unclear on how to do that.

I feel like there ought abstractly to be a way to change the Cookie / JWT / Authentication code to say "all those vouchers that you handed out previously? None of them are valid anymore."

Is there a particular thing I should be looking to find and change?

I appreciate that the answer may boil down to "it depends on the minutiae of how your system configures its vouchers, and we can't give an answer without seeing that code". But I think I'd need to post 5 different copies of the question for each part of the system that does this with a different library/tech stack.

But I'm hoping there might exist any answer along the lines of "Just increment / change the "JWTVersion" property of set up code, and it'll do exactly what you want. You just need to search for "how to change JWTVersion" for the specific library you're using in each part of the system."

Comment: Change the secret?

Comment: ... sure ... that sounds plausible. What secret?

Comment: As you're aware (since you edited it out of the question) ... I don't know anything about how these systems work ... so I don't know what secret these vouchers have, or how it's used/configured.

Comment: An answer of "you just need to google "JWT + <the name used for the secret in JWTs>", and change that" sounds entirley plausible.

Answer (score 0):

One option for solving the scenario desire, which I've seen online is to do a pre-cursor release that "poisons" the expiry date on the access vouchers:

- Declare that the release will be at 09:00 on Saturday morning.
- Do a Preparatory Release on *Monday* morning that starts creating all vouchers with an expiry date of 09:05 on Saturday.
- Turn the system off at 09:00 on Saturday.
- Put the system into MM and turn it back on at 09:10 on Saturday, with the expiry date poison removed.
- Now **everyone's** token has expired, they need to log back in, and only allowed people can get past the login screen.

But A) that requires extra releases and code changes. And B) ... it doesn't feel like a very clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are right that the solution greatly depends on some architectural decisions made in your system. Here are some thoughts that might help you:

1. I think that you will have to touch all the places in your environment wherever the voucher is validated. The code that validates vouchers should not accept ones issued before a specific point in time (when you started the MM).
2. If you have a central point of entry to your system, like a reverse-proxy or an API gateway, even some load-balancers, then this is a good place to implement the logic that would reject requests with vouchers issued before MM started.
3. For JWTs it should be quite trivial as a standard JWT issued in an OAuth flow should contain an `iat` claim — issued at. You can then reject tokens that have the `iat` claim set to lower than your selected timestamp.
4. It might be a bit more tricky for cookies, as I don't know what data you get in the cookie. If you get some information about the time of issuance, or if you can derive it (e.g. you have the expiration time and you know that your system always sets the expiration time to 1 hour, so you can calculate the issuance time), then it's also possible to reject those cookies.

Anyway, I think it boils down to the overall architecture of your system — whether you have a central point-of-entry or where are the points where vouchers are validated. Still, I think you will have to update code of your apps/gateways. I don't think something you describe is possible just with a configuration option.